# Kindle Unlimited superhero book about a teenage boy who can control technology

Tags: story-identification, books

I don’t remember a ton about it, but I do remember that the main character found himself able to control technology and started stealing at one point. He was caught by a different superhero and brought to a school to learn how to use his powers. He was adopted I believe by some billionaire tech designer that works with superheroes.

I don’t remember a ton, but I know that I read it on Kindle Unlimited, I want to say 1-2 years ago. No idea when it was written, but still. It might have been taken off of Kindle Unlimited at this point, but I’m not 100% sure. Any help would be heavily appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: If you'd like to earn some more reputation, why not submit the correct title as an answer rather than editing it into your question? If you don't post it as an answer, another user likely will, and in doing so, they'll earn the rep that could've been yours. If you do submit an answer here, you can also mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, although, as it would be a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have passed since you first posted the question.

Comment: @North: I've posted your find as an answer. Feel free to copy any or all of my answer for your own. As noted, that will let you get the credit for the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Sorry bout that, very new to this site. Thank you though.

Comment: Note to others who may be trying to remember a book they read on Kindle Unlimited: you can get a full list of everything you've ever borrowed by going to the "Kindle Unlimited" link on your popup menu (in a browser) and then scrolling down. And scrolling down. And scrolling down some more. Eventually, it'll load everything, if the internet gods are being cooperative.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Fuzzy Boots for writing this out.

[*EMERGENCE: The Super Smart Superhero*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/57129859-emergence) by Whiskey Flowers, published in 2021.

[image: Front cover of EMERGENCE: The Super Smart Superhero]

Summary from [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3935551618):

> Kind of hard to explain this one. The MC is the son of a super villain. He has the power of super smell. His father was a mad genius and injected him with nanites while he was child and now he is also a super computer. He can interact with any system. He is captured by super heroes and put into a super school until he turns 18. This is the law. the school is weird because there are kids there that say they are going to be villains when they get out. The superhero students aren't that good. The MC is adopted by the richest guy in the world (think Tony Stark). The MC is treated well by the other supers, by his new father, or by the government. Out of all of them, the government is probably the worst. I didn't get the goal of this book. Things just kind of happened and I kept asking myself why? Why did the author go this way. Where is he taking me. There isn't much personal interactions, the story is told with sort of a flat voice. Despite that it was still a quick and easy read and it was interesting. I am going to pick up the next book to see if I can figure out where the author is going with the story. Is it a good place or a bad place?

Thanks to those who helped me out. I don’t remember if this book is any good or not, just have a strange addiction to superhero stories at the moment (at least, the ones that aren’t for small children). If anyone has any recommendations, shoot them at me any time. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for returning. Don't forget to accept the answer. I hope you'll stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Partial match would be the *[H.I.V.E.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/HIVESeries)* series. Otto is indeed caught and abducted to a school to train his powers.

> *H.I.V.E.*: Otto Malpense is kidnapped and taken to a school for villains. Here he meets five other new students and some of them make an escape attempt together. It doesn't work. The headmaster, Dr Nero, knew what they were up to the whole time. They're just about to be punished for it when something large, green and carnivorous interrupts. And it's not the Hulk.

However, he believes himself to just be a very good hacker at the beginning of the series. He doesn't realize his technopathic abilities until later when one of his schoolmates point out that his rapid-fire typing has nothing to do with what the computer is doing. Also, it's a school for villains, which I figure you would have mentioned.